# CSS @Font face rule not working for text boxes

Tags: css, asp.net, fonts

I am creating an asp.net website in which I am using css to set the fonts to controls.This is the CSS:

```
body {
}

@font-face
{
   font-family: MyFont;
   src: url("Shiv05.eot");
}
@font-face
{
   font-family: MyFont;
   src: url("Shiv05.ttf") ;
}
@font-face
{
   font-family: MyFont;
   src: url("Shiv05.woff") ;
}
    .Title
   {
       font-family: MyFont, Arial;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 16px;
       color: #0094ff;
    }
    .Text
    {
       font-family: MyFont, Arial;
       font-size: 18px;
       color:Lime;
    }
```

And this is how I am using it in my source:

```
div class="Text">       
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" 
Height="101px"  TextMode="MultiLine"
                    Width="627px"  meta:resourcekey="txtQuestionResource1" 
                    ontextchanged="txtQuestion_TextChanged" Font-Names="Shivaji05"
                    EnableTheming="False"></asp:TextBox>          

                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionText" runat="server" 
 Text="Type Your Question   Here" 
                Font-Bold="True" EnableTheming="False" Font-Names="Shivaji05">    </asp:Label>                   
                 </div>
```

The font gets applied to the label but not to the text box,where is the mistake and how should I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What matters here is what HTML element is generated by the ASP code. For `TextMode="MultiLine"`, it is a `textarea` element, so that’s what you need to set your styles on, for example:

```
.Text textarea
{
   font-family: MyFont, Arial;
}
```

Setting the font for `.Text` does not affect the `textarea`, since `textarea` elements have a browser-dependent default font; in terms of CSS, this means that at least conceptually, there is a browser style sheet that sets `font-family` on `textarea`. Therefore a `textarea` element does not inherit font from its parent.

Comment: thank you so much for clarifying this, makes sense what you just said.

Comment: Wow @Jukka K. Korpela,great bit of information, and it has finally worked for me.Also good help from Andre